# Can any function be written as product of infinite number of polynomials

Tags: real-analysis

By Taylor's series we can say that every function can be written as power series form or loosely we can say infinite polynomials, 
But when see sin(x) can be written as x(1-x/ℼ)(1-x/2ℼ)
(1+x/ℼ)(1+x/2ℼ).....
So is it possible for other functions

Comment: First off, Taylor's series are only defined on smooth functions. Moreover, it only equals the function over its entire domain if it is analytic. So no, this is only possible for analytic functions.

Comment: Kind of: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem